# Ember cli auto generated routes confusion

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am making a simple todo list in Ember using the Ember cli, and I am running into some confusion with the folder structure and code that is getting auto generated.

In my routes folder I have a items.js that defines the model to be rendered to the template and it works fine. But in the console is telling me that it is auto generating an route:items.index

```
    generated -> route:items.index Object {fullName: "route:items.index"}
```

I added the items folder to the routes folder and an index.js to the items folder. Which clears up that console line. But it doesn't actually affect anything. I can console log out from it, but setting the model to return different data doesn't change what is displayed at /items. If I then try removing my routes/items.js and run it. I tells me that it is auto generating that file, but nothing displays, because it still doesn't use items index

```
    generated -> route:items Object {fullName: "route:items"}
```

Can anyone explain what is happening here, what is the difference between routes/items and route/items/index ? Why does it need both, and why does the app completely ignore the latter.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a route under your item's resource.  Add `{{outlet}}` to your item's template, and then  create a new template `items/index` and put some random text in it.  You'll see when you're on the `items` resource `/items` and only the `items` resource it will render the `index` template.  This is a way of rendering something special when they hit the root of a particular resource and no deeper.